# What is a good reference to cite for the definition of forms in terms of germs of functions?

Tags: reference-request, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology, germs

I would like to edit the Wikipedia articles [[Differential (infinitesimal)]] and [[Differential form]] to mention the definition of 1-forms in terms of germs of functions. None of the appropriate references that I have are available online. Can anybody suggest a good online reference, or at least a good reference that is still in print?

I wouldn't object if someone else wanted to do the edits, but I don't expect it.

Thanks.